# Jasmine test on angular sidenav with routing

Tags: angular, routes, jasmine

I have a component with routing like this :

```
<div>
  <div class="d-flex px-2 py-3">
    <a
      class="navbar-brand p-0"
      aria-label="AdAsia"
      [routerLink]="[routes.pages.dashboard.children.home.link]"
    >
      <app-logo [logoType]="logoType"></app-logo>
    </a>
  </div>

  <nav class="nav flex-column mb-4 flex-column">
    <p
      class="nav-item w-100 rounded-sm mb-2"
      #home="routerLinkActive"
      [routerLinkActive]="['active']"
    >
      <a
        class="nav-link text-m text-truncate p-1"
        [routerLink]="[routes.pages.dashboard.children.home.link]"
      >
        <svg-icon [hidden]="!home.isActive" src="assets/svg/dooh-dashboard-dark.svg"></svg-icon>
        <svg-icon [hidden]="home.isActive" src="assets/svg/dooh-dashboard-light.svg"></svg-icon>
        {{ 'PAGES.DASHBOARD.NAME' | translate }}
      </a>
    </p>
    <p
      class="nav-item w-100 rounded-sm mb-2"
      #report="routerLinkActive"
      [routerLinkActive]="['active']"
    >
      <a
        class="nav-link text-m text-truncate p-1"
        [routerLink]="[routes.pages.dashboard.children.reports.link]"
      >
        <svg-icon [hidden]="!report.isActive" src="assets/svg/report-dark.svg"></svg-icon>
        <svg-icon [hidden]="report.isActive" src="assets/svg/report-light.svg"></svg-icon>
        {{ 'PAGES.REPORTS.NAME' | translate }}
      </a>
    </p>
  </nav>
</div>
```

I try to test it with the following :

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing'
import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core'
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core'

import { LogoTypeEnum } from '@app/types'
import { SidenavComponent } from './sidenav.component'

describe('SidenavComponent', () => {
  let component: SidenavComponent
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<SidenavComponent>

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
      declarations: [SidenavComponent],
      imports: [TranslateModule.forRoot()],
    })
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SidenavComponent)
    component = fixture.componentInstance
  })

  it('can load instance', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy()
  })

  it('logoType has default value', () => {
    expect(component.logoType).toEqual(LogoTypeEnum.DARK)
  })
})
```

But I had a `routerActiveLink` do not exist error.

So I create following another answer a stub like this

```
import { Directive, Input, HostListener } from '@angular/core'

@Directive({
  /* tslint:disable-next-line */
  selector: '[routerLink]',
})
export class RouterLinkStubDirective {
  /* tslint:disable-next-line */
  @Input('routerLink') linkParams: any
  navigatedTo: any = null

  @HostListener('click')
  onClick() {
    this.navigatedTo = this.linkParams
  }
}
```

and updated the jasmine test

```
@Component({
  template: ``,
})
export class HomeComponent {}

@Component({
  template: ``,
})
export class EditComponent {}

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'edit',
    component: EditComponent,
  },
]

describe('SidenavComponent', () => {
  let component: SidenavComponent
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<SidenavComponent>
  let router: Router

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
      imports: [RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(routes), TranslateModule.forRoot()],
      declarations: [SidenavComponent, RouterLinkStubDirective, HomeComponent, EditComponent],
    }).compileComponents()
  }))

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SidenavComponent)
    component = fixture.componentInstance
    router = TestBed.get(Router)
    fixture.detectChanges()
  })

  it('can be instantiated', () => {
    expect(component).not.toBeNull()
  })
})
```

but now I get `can't find property pages of undefined`

but I have no idea where this is coming from.

How do I fix this ?

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to mock it properly, try to use [ng-mocks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-mocks) for example.

Also you need to provide `routes` to the tested component via providers:

```js
providers: [{
  provide: NAME_WHAT_YOU_IMPORT,
  useValue: {
    pages: {
      dashboard: {
        children: {
          home: {
            link: 'test-link',
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
}],
```